# When I open a scene my Unity crashes. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error logs. Unity is not running.

> Unity.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)   in module
>   Unity.exe at 0033:41ac1fd9.

Full log:

```
Unity Editor [version: Unity 2017.2.3p1_b4bae9093154]

Unity.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module Unity.exe at 0033:41ac1fd9.

Error occurred at 2018-06-12_191314.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe, run by Hemal Dedhia.
23% memory in use.
32721 MB physical memory [25171 MB free].
37585 MB paging file [29247 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134211053 MB free].
Read from location 00000000 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x00000000  RSI: 0x00000000  RAX:   0x5a7a4680
RBX:    0x005f9930  RCX: 0xffffffff  RDX:   0x00000000
RIP:    0x41ac1fd9  RBP: 0x00000000  SegCs: 0x00000033
EFlags: 0x00010246  RSP: 0x005f98c0  SegSs: 0x0000002b
R8:    0x00000000  R9: 0x86839907  R10:   0x00000028
R11:    0x005f98b0  R12: 0x00041900  R13:   0x403b8e10
R14:    0x405096b4  R15: 0x00000018

Bytes at CS:EIP:
39 2f 75 0f 48 8b 47 08 48 83 f8 ff 74 08 48 3b

Stack:
0x005f98c0: 403b8cc0 00000000 005f9930 00000000 ..;@....0._.....
0x005f98d0: 00000000 00000000 7d6ac5af 000002a1 ..........j}....
0x005f98e0: 403b8e10 00000000 41ae5f5a 00000001 ..;@....Z_.A....
0x005f98f0: 00000000 00000000 04d35d80 00000000 .........]......
0x005f9900: 00000000 00000000 00000004 00000000 ................
0x005f9910: 00041998 00000000 00000003 00000000 ................
0x005f9920: 403b8e10 00000000 41ae7182 00000001 ..;@.....q.A....
0x005f9930: 0001293e 00000000 5af369f0 00000000 >).......i.Z....
0x005f9940: 4044f390 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..D@............
0x005f9950: 5af2bef0 00000000 5af369f0 00000000 ...Z.....i.Z....
0x005f9960: 00000003 00000000 7d6ac4df 000002a1 ..........j}....
0x005f9970: 000018d5 00000000 7d6ac50f 000002a1 ..........j}....
0x005f9980: 00041998 00000000 4098fa71 00000001 ........q..@....
0x005f9990: 449cabd0 00000001 449cab90 00000001 ...D.......D....
0x005f99a0: 449cab90 00000001 00000003 00000000 ...D............
0x005f99b0: 4044f390 00000000 000426e6 00000000 ..D@.....&......
0x005f99c0: 4475e3d0 00000001 00000000 00000000 ..uD............
0x005f99d0: 00000000 ffffffff 449cab90 00000001 ...........D....
0x005f99e0: 00000000 00000000 fffffffe ffffffff ................
0x005f99f0: 40509690 00000000 4098e362 00000001 ..P@....b..@....
0x005f9a00: 40509a50 00000000 41038600 00000001 P.P@.......A....
0x005f9a10: 40984550 00000001 00000000 00000000 PE.@............
0x005f9a20: 49074478 00000000 00000018 00000000 xD.I............
0x005f9a30: 00000000 00000000 40509690 00000000 ..........P@....
```

Comment: Did you have a question? Seems like it's corrupted. Do you have a backup?

Comment: Backup of what, my project or my unity.

Comment: Do you have a minimal code example?

Comment: What do you mean. Code for what.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to Unity?

Comment: Yes, a backup of your project, or maybe just your scene file. Is your project set to force text or are your assets binary?

Comment: Is it hapening when you open  *any* scene, or a *specific scene* ?